# Webstart security dialog is shown when fetching a HTTP URL that gets redirected

Tags: java, security, redirect, java-web-start

We have an application that is deployed with Java WebStart. There is a JEditorPane that shows some HTML content. This HTML also contains images. If the server returns a HTTP 3xx staus code because the actual resource was moved a WebStart security dialog is shown. This dialog asks the user for confirmation whether the application should be allowe to fetch data from a certain host.

A very simple sample application:

```
package test;

import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main extends JFrame {

public Main() {

    JEditorPane p = new JEditorPane();
    p.setContentType("text/html");
    p.setEditable(false);
    p.setText("<html><img src=\"XXXX\" /></html>");

    add(p);

    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(500, 500);
    setVisible(true);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Main();
        }
    });
}

}
```

XXXX -> http://www.hon.ch/HONcode/Seal/HONConduct432264.jpg
Security dialog appears

XXXX -> http://www.uni-due.de/imperia/md/images/cms/ude-logo.png
**No** security dialog appears

The JNLP file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="6.0+" codebase="." href="xxx.jnlp">
<information>
    <title>xxx</title>
    <vendor>xxx</vendor>
</information>
<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>
<update check="always" policy="always" />
<resources>
    <java version="1.7+" java-vm-args="-Xmx150m" />
    <jar href="xxx-signed.jar" main="true" />
</resources>
<application-desc main-class="test.Main">
</application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Is there an easy way to disable these security dialogs? If not we have to fetch the images via our application backend.

Comment: If your app. is trusted the dialogs should not appear.  Have you checked the bug database?

Comment: The application is signed with a trustworthy certificate. The "standard" WebStart security dialogs are not shown. The dialog mentioned above only appears when the JEditorPane loads the HTML content. I didn't find any related bugs in the bug database. Also, the application crashes when the dialog appears because there is a deadlock between the UI thread and a WebStart thread (using the latest Java 7 version).

Comment: *"I didn't find any related bugs in the bug database."*  Raise one & let's see what Oracle has to say about it.

Comment: Done. Just wanted to check if it's an error from our side ;)